# Intel WiFi Card Not Recognised in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, intel-wireless

My Wifi card is not being recognised. I think it may be because the hardware is relatively new (it's a new Dell Precision Laptop). Have been trying to figure out how to backport new drivers but that seems enabled already so perhaps I have to move to a newer kernel. I have pasted below the output from the wifi script. Any suggestions much appreciated!

```
Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0050]

02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1bcf:2b95 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 413c:2501 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

dell_wmi               16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  2 dell_wmi,intel_hid
wmi                    20480  2 dell_led,dell_wmi
video                  40960  2 i915_bpo,dell_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]> Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:10.0.0.68  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::85dc:a2e3:6213:17fa/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:27486 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16153 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:38038652 (38.0 MB)  TX bytes:1484440 (1.4 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3393 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3393 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:296423 (296.4 KB)  TX bytes:296423 (296.4 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.138      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       850     1  0 08:44 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        USB 10/100/1000 LAN
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8152
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 v1.08.2
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.6/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:02.0/0000:3d:00.0/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/net/enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       59d22e27-8ac3-3f8b-b594-ac8358b7509d
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   59d22e27-8ac3-3f8b-b594-ac8358b7509d | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.0.0.68/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.0.0.138
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.0.0.138
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1493765196
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 10.0.0.68
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       routers = 10.0.0.138
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 10.0.0.255
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       domain_name_servers = 10.0.0.138
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 10.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 10.0.0.138
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::85dc:a2e3:6213:17fa/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Australia/Sydney (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# USB device 0x:0x (r8152)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

##### dmesg #############################

[  161.590850] r8152 4-1:1.0 eth0: v1.08.2
[  162.462586] r8152 4-1:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: renamed from eth0
[  162.485824] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[  166.139113] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the kernel version included in Ubuntu 16.04, your exact device 8086:24fd and subsystem 0050 are not yet covered. It is covered in Ubuntu 17.04; from my machine:

```
$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep 0050
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024FDsv*sd00000050bc*sc*i*
```

You could certainly reinstall and use 17.04 instead of 16.04. You could also download and install the 4.10-xx kernel and required firmware. If you'd prefer to do the latter, then I assume that your installation is 64-bit; confirm:

```
arch
```

If the terminal returns x86_64 then yours is a 64-bit install. Download the files to your desktop:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.10.14/linux-headers-4.10.14-041014_4.10.14-041014.201705031501_all.deb

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.10.14/linux-headers-4.10.14-041014-generic_4.10.14-041014.201705031501_amd64.deb

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.10.14/linux-image-4.10.14-041014-generic_4.10.14-041014.201705031501_amd64.deb

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.164_all.deb

Install them all from the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Reboot and tell us if your wireless is working.

Comment: Thank you very much @chili555! I am sure this would work...I'm just a bit reluctant to move to 17.04 or update the kernel at this point as I've just spent a lot of time reinstalling after a separate issue. I'm going to use an external USB wifi device that is working for a while...and reassess in a few weeks. Thanks again!

Comment: I have now moved to 17.04 and wireless is working well now. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, that worked! Been searching for a solution for the last 5 hours and none in the Internet worked. Confirming that the solution works for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Inter Corporation Unclaimed wifi card.

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm for me, I'm using a dell latitude 5580 with Intel network hardware.

Comment: Goodness is there a way to upvote 20 times? This saved me a ton of trouble!

Comment: @chili555 worked fine for hp laptop for ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: This works great! The 4th link is expired and I have to get it from launchpad.net

Answer (score 3):

Installing a kernel outside of repository is not a good idea because you will miss security updates. You should install the [Ubuntu HWE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) instead.

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

This will upgrade your kernel and xorg stack. At this time, it would upgrade you to the kernel of Ubuntu 17.10 (kernel 4.13).

Comment: Is the X.org upgrade really necessary to get the wireless adapter drivers? Probably not…

Comment: Probably not, but this is the documented way to upgrade the HWE. It doesn't hurt to upgrade X.org anyway. - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack