# My wifi is hard blocked in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, wifi-hardware-switch

My wifi is not working in Ubuntu 16.04, it is hard blocked, but there is no any physical switch that i can turn it on. Here are some useful info about my device:

```
##### lspci #############################

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [8086:15b8]
Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [1849:15b8]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1849:1539]
Kernel driver in use: igb

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1010]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi


##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04f3:0103 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ActiveJet    K-2024 Multimedia Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 258a:1007  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes

 ##### lsmod #############################

iwlmvm                385024  0
mac80211              782336  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               249856  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              614400  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
wmi                    24576  0
```

I looked into almost all similar questions. non of them was useful, I tried many solutions described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151098/wi-fi-doesnt-work-hard-blocked) and the 47 answers, but I am still having the problem

This is the output of the `lsmod | grep wmi`

```
##########  lsmod | grep wmi #############

snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd                    81920  21      snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
wmi                    24576  0
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intel WiFi Card Not Recognised in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910934/intel-wifi-card-not-recognised-in-ubuntu-16-04). A simple wired update might solve the problem, as you should get newer kernel and firmware packages. If possible, connect an ethernet cable, install updates, and reboot.

Comment: I tried installing the four files mentioned in the referenced answer, and the problem still there!!

Comment: The problems that I can not switch it on from the network manager. The switch goes back automatically to off

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsmod | grep wmi`

Comment: @chili555done. Does it tell anything?