# Network unclaimed on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless

Ubuntu is not able to detect Wi-Fi and also the network is unclaimed.

I don't have Ethernet cable nor any dongle is there any way I can fix it without any internet connection on my laptop.

Output of `lshw -c network`:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:3f:00.0
   version: 78
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:8a200000-8a201fff
```

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
3f:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1010]
40:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co     Ltd Device [144d:a804]
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:a801]
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

Kernel version:

```
Linux yoga 4.4.0-119-generic #143-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 2 16:08:24 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: You can access internet by using USB Tethering on a smartphone with internet connection.

Comment: Also please post the kernel version `uname -a`.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have edited my question.

Comment: Now it is clear. I am writing an answer that will solve it. Meanwhile please remove the screenshots and replace them with text. You can copy text from terminal and paste it as text.

Comment: I am new to this

Comment: Duplicate of : https://askubuntu.com/questions/910934/intel-wifi-card-not-recognised-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @MatsK The accepted answer of that question is obsolete.

Comment: @Pilot6 Please correct that answer so it is up to date instead of creating duplicates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intel WiFi Card Not Recognised in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910934/intel-wifi-card-not-recognised-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: @MatsK There is a correct answer there, but it is not accepted. I think it is better to mark the other one as a dupe of this one.

Comment: @Pilot6 And lose the history, I think that's a bad decision. Let's move this discussion to "Ubuntu Meta"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You installed Ubuntu 16.04 with the original 4.4 kernel that doesn't support your new wireless adapter.

If you downloaded and installed the 16.04.4 image, it would work without any additional effort.

For now the easiest solution is to upgrade the kernel. Connect to the internet by some other means (wire, tethering, etc) and run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-firmware
```

Reboot after the kernel packages are installed. Your wireless adapter should work.

Comment: After doing the above you mentioned my wifi is working  but I am having problem with shutdown and reboot (only a black screen comes and nothing happens)

Comment: There may be issues with your graphics adapter and its driver with this kernel. You can always boot with the old kernel using `grub`. You can also ask a new question. But I suggest to start with updating your system with `sudo apt upgrade` first. Or do a fresh install of 16.04.4.

Comment: Did not work.I am posting it as a new question

Answer (score 0):

A rough but simple way to fix - reinstall Ubuntu with "Install 3rd party software for graphics and wifi hardware" checkbox, this will load necessary driver