# Kernel: 5.11, Wi-Fi UNCLAIMED, "dmesg |grep iwlwifi" is empty. Wifi [8086:2725] Subsystem [1a56:1673] has nothing on internet

Tags: networking, drivers, 21.04, iwlwifi

What I have different from all other cases is that I have nothing on dmesg.

```
# dmesg |grep iwlwifi | wc -l
0
```

- I have dual boot with Windows 10.
- Windows "Fast Startup" is disabled.
- Secure boot is disabled (I have it enabled when install the linux, but disable to fix nvidia).
- Ubuntu 21 "Ubuntu 21.04.
- The classic "Ubuntu Drivers" only offer drivers for NVidia

```
# inxi -Fxxxrz
System:    Kernel: 5.11.0-34-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.1 Desktop: GNOME 3.38.4 tk: GTK 3.24.25 
           wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 3.38.2.1 Distro: Ubuntu 21.04 (Hirsute Hippo) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Alienware product: Alienware x17 R1 v: 1.2.1 serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 10 
           serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: Alienware model: Alienware x17 R1 v: A00 serial: <filter> UEFI: Alienware v: 1.2.1 date: 07/12/2021 
...
Network:   Device-1: Realtek Killer E3000 2.5GbE vendor: Dell driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 3000 bus ID: 0000:3b:00.0 
           chip ID: 10ec:3000 class ID: 0200 
           IF: enp59s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz vendor: Rivet Networks driver: N/A port: 3000 bus ID: 0000:3c:00.0 
           chip ID: 8086:2725 class ID: 0280 
           IF-ID-1: docker0 state: down mac: <filter> 
...
```

```
# lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net 
0000:3b:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Killer E3000 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:3000] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a8f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
0000:3c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Rivet Networks Device [1a56:1673]
```

```
# mokutil --sb-state
SecureBoot disabled
```

```
# rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
# sudo lshw -c network
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3c:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:87200000-87203fff
```

```
# apt info linux-firmware | grep Version
Version: 1.197.3
```

In [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1902848) it say that device [8086:2725] Subsystem [8086:4020] was added to linux-firmware 1.187.7. But lspic say mine is [1a56:1673], that I can not find anything in internet.

Edit:

This is what windows see, it come installed on from factory.

[image]

Trying to enable iwlwifi, still no logs:

```
# lsmod | grep iwlwifi
<emtpy>

# modinfo iwlwifi | grep -i version
srcversion:     C4766991DE91166408C39CE
vermagic:       5.11.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions

# modprobe iwlwifi
<empty>

# dmesg | grep -i iwl
<empty>
```

**Edit 3**

I enable panic mode and clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git and copy into my /lib/firmware. Everything is the same with exception of

```
# lsmod | grep iwlwifi
iwlwifi               380928  0
cfg80211              892928  1 iwlwifi
```

Comment: Fast Boot is a UEFI feature; **Fast Startup** is a Windows feature and the one you should disable.

Comment: It looks like the driver for the wifi device did not load.  Try powering the machine off and booting directly into linux without booting windows in between.   Make sure you have installed the firmware for the wifi card.  Find the name of the driver and try manually loading it with modprobe and look for errors in system messages (via `/var/log/syslog` or `dmesg`).

Comment: @ChanganAuto sorry, I am talking about "Fast Startup" on window. I follow the guide using adm power and uncheck the feature.

Comment: @user10489 I boot everyday directly on linux. I only login on windows few times trying to fix this.

Both dmesg and syslog are empty by "grep -i iwl".

Searching for the "8086:2725", the launchpad 1902848. It say that device was added on linux-firmware on version 1.187.7. Mine is 1.197.3. But, they say "Subsystem [8086:4020]". Where my lspci say "Subsystem: Rivet Networks Device [1a56:1673]", 1a56:1673 is non existent in internet :/

Comment: @Sisso that's because it's a subsystem of the Wi-Fi card. Your card is an Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411.

Comment: There's a few cards that windows initializes in ways linux can't undo, which is why I suggested the power cycle -- but likely this is not one of them anyway.  Do you know the module name for the driver this card needs? I didn't find it in a quick search.

Comment: @user10489 I don't know what drivers. Honestly I barely know how to find it. I normally search for Ids and find enough information. This one is a bit differently.

Comment: I'm not finding any information on this device, it is possible it isn't supported yet.  It looks like it should be supported by the iwlwifi driver.  If you run `lsmod | grep iwlwifi` is it loaded?  If not, do you get any system messages from `modprobe iwlwifi` ?  Can you give us the version number from `modinfo iwlwifi` ?  And check https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html and see if your card is listed and if you already have the correct firmware.

Comment: Intel's main support page for this is https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi

Comment: @user10489 added the lsmod commands you asked.

Comment: About search driver. What botter me is why I don't find any from ID. And why the name on lspic don't match wtih windows.

Comment: grep dmesg isn't gonna give you anything.   Do a `tail -f /var/log/syslog ` and then do `modprobe iwlwifi` and give us everything that came out of the tail in between.  There's some reason the module isn't loading -- either it doesn't recognize the card or it isn't finding the firmware or some other error.

Comment: It's at least helpful to be sure the module isn't loading (not in lsmod), and I'll have to backtrack the version and see when (if?) your card was added.

Comment: @user10489 I try to add head of linux firmaware git and reboot. I have something in lsmod, but all others are the same. After this, I try again modprob tailing the syslog, still nothing, not a single line.

Any chance that this driver could have being installed with secure boot on, and now that I have it disable fail? Odd.. but...never knows.

Comment: I don't have one of these devices, and when I `modprobe iwlwifi` I get 3 lines, none of which includes "iwlwifi" in them.  If you are getting "nothing", either you are missing an error or you are missing the lines where it loads.

Comment: 1) Check `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist...` files. 
2) `... grep iwlwifi` showing no lines is not a sign of problems. I get the same (and I also use `iwlwifi`).
3) Even if old, https://askubuntu.com/a/1052413/226614 ... check for firmware. Also https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/es-ar/000144425/killer-wireless-firmware-update-guide-for-ubuntu-systems and https://forum.garudalinux.org/t/intel-ax210-wifi-not-working-after-installation/7900/11
4) Your kernel version should suffice, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301607/wifi-intel-ax210ngw-is-not-recognized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According with the git commits in linux kernel, the device was added on Apr 14 [1] ("Valeu luca!") and is available only in kernel 5.13[2]. Not yet on Ubuntu 21.04.

[1] https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/62fb9874f5da54fdb243003b386128037319b219/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/drv.c#L622

[2] https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.13/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/drv.c

Comment: If this is the case, you could download the 21.10 Daily Build .iso and use that until 21.10 ships next month. The release is pretty solid and uses the 5.13.14 kernel 

Comment: Everything is working with Ubuntu 21.10 and Kernel 5.13