# MSI mobo onboard Intel WiFi not detected

Tags: wireless, intel, msi

First time Ubuntu user here. I’ve google’d this answer and am at a loss. I have a built in intel WiFi adaptor on my mobo but Ubuntu doesn’t see it. It recognizes it’s intel but that’s it. Not sure what to do from here?

Network control [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0024]   Kernel driver in use : iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi

Uname -r
5.11.0-27-generic

Ubuntu version is 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: "It recognizes it’s intel but that’s it." Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `uname -r` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Also show us: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` in an edit.

Comment: 5.11 is a kernel; and is used by multiple releases - please provide OS & release details.   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide is most useful, esp. the *Device recognition and Operation* section

Comment: Thanks. I’m trying to figure out the best way to transfer all that info. I’m on mobile since my pc network is down. The sudo dmesg command is a long list

Comment: Can you tether your phone?

Comment: Yes my version is 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364424/kernel-5-11-wi-fi-unclaimed-dmesg-grep-iwlwifi-is-empty-wifi-80862725 I suggest that you install Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: FYI:  Using the 20.04.4 ISO may also have better results; it's using the same 5.13 kernel as found in Ubuntu 21.10 (*instead of 5.11 kernel stack from 21.04 used by 20.04.3 media*) but sorry I have no experience with your hardware

Comment: Okay thanks guys. I’ll try updating Ubuntu. I had troubles with this driver with windows as well.

Comment: Is there an easy way to update to a newer version without internet and without doing a clean install ?

Comment: You can *upgrade via re-install* using later media; ie. an *unclean* install.