# Wireless not detected after installing update, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers

I performed an update a couple of days ago on Ubuntu 16.04. Since then wifi is not detected at all.

I tried re-installing the proprietary drivers. Also tried

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

This didn't work. I did notice though the following message about the firmware

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin for module i915
```

I am using an intel 3rd generation graphics card.

If anyone can help give an insight into why Wifi is no longer working, I would be most grateful.

Thanks

Comment: You have to first check the card provider like Intel or Broadcom using the command lspci If its Intel then follow the steps mentioned in post:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/910934/intel-wifi-card-not-recognised-in-ubuntu-16-04 Special thanks to https://askubuntu.com/users/19421/chili555

Comment: Hi, thank you for your contribution, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! From the looks of things, this question may be a duplicate of the question you linked (which itself, is a duplicate!). I'm going to convert your answer to a comment (as that would be more appropriate). If the OP confirms that this suggestion works, then this question can indeed be closed as a duplicate of the other.