# I can't connect to the internet ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I have a xiaomi air 13 intel 7, I installed ubuntu 14.04 lts along with windows 10, the windows side can connect ethernet and to wifi but ubuntu's side can't, 
what can I do ?
Thanks in advance 
Ps: I am a new user

I installed 
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.10.14/linux-headers-4.10.14-041014_4.10.14-041014.201705031501_all.deb

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.10.14/linux-headers-4.10.14-041014-generic_4.10.14-041014.201705031501_amd64.deb

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.10.14/linux-image-4.10.14-041014-generic_4.10.14-041014.201705031501_amd64.deb  install
And also this
 linux-firmware_1.173.1.tar.gz

But I still can't have internet conection can someone help me please

Comment: Why install a 4 years old release?

Comment: Because I need to use it for another program that only runs in this version

Comment: I seriously doubt it but if you say so... Just be aware that (1) 14.04 has just a few months left of support (2) newer versions may support your WiFi natively and (3) 14.04 may not support it at all. Anyway please [edit] and post the results of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`.

Comment: Network controller  [0280]:intel corporation device [8086:24fd ] (rev 78) Subsystem: Intel corporation device [8086:9010]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to post additional/request information. Do not do it in comments. But now that we identified the device please read https://askubuntu.com/a/911855/880592 and understand the earliest supported release with support for that WiFi is 18.04, exactly what I told you from the start. Now do yourself a favor and find a more recent version of the "software that only runs in 14.04", a different software or use an old, already supported, USB WiFi device instead.

Comment: Thanks so much,  I will download the files and installed them,  im sure it will work,  I will update you as soon as it is done

Comment: If by "files" you mean the new kernel version than yes, it may work but at the same time your "software that only runs in 14.04" most likely won't because if it does then it must also run in 16.04 or 18.04, kernel is what matters.

Comment: One of the kernel,  the last one
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.169.1_all.deb. says it doesn't exist is there other one I could use ?